# My Perl program Stas

Tags: perl, statistics, cpu, profile

I need your help to implement something to monitor CPU/MEM usage during or at the end of the execution of a perl program.

Imagine that a program that runs every N minutes which is launched by another Perl program, the execution of the latter can vary from a few seconds to 1 minute. How can I get CPU/MEM usage that result from executing this program.

some of the requirements are:

- monitoring should interfere as little
  as possible with the execution of the
  program.
- monitoring should use a minimum of
  system resources
- OS independent as possible. should
  run in Linux, Win32, HP-UX, Solaris,
  AIX. Ok but lets focus first in
  Linux.

I've thought in some approaches:

1. Implement my own Devel::MyProfiler
   and run the program with -d
   "option". (ex: $ perl -dMyProfiler
   program.pl)
2. Implement a wrapper that get stats
   every N seconds from /proc/pid or "$
   ps aux", and gets the average stats
   at the end of the program
3. Implement a parallel program that
   makes a "$ ps aux" every N seconds
4. Using a process trace tool!!
5. ???

Any tip will be helpfull!!!

**Note:** this question was also posted in http://perlmonks.com/?node_id=909934

Tks,

gulden

Comment: Cross-posted to Perlmonks: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=909934

Answer (score 1):

A profiler or trace tool is probably the wrong approach to this problem, as it'll have a performance (and memory usage) impact on the program you're running. Probably not what you want.

Most UNIX-y operating systems support system calls like `getrusage()`, which will let you get resource utilization stats for the current process or for child processes. There's a Perl interface for that in `Unix::Getrusage`; alternatively, most UNIX systems have a `time` utility and/or shell builtin that'll gather statistics on a child process.

Windows is a black box to me, so I'm not sure if it has any equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

If you do want profiling look at
      http://open.blogs.nytimes.com/2008/03/05/the-new-york-times-perl-profiler

The overhead is reasonable.  The memory map is very helpful.